# JQuery - Add todays date to div when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add todays date inside a div when a checkbox has been checked. I can get this to work in the console but not on the page. I don't get any console errors when I run the script in the console or whne the page is loaded. I've tried adding:

```
$( document ).ready(function()
```

to the script, but I get an error. Here is my script:

```
function GetTodayDate() {
  var tdate = new Date();
  var dd = tdate.getDate(); //yields day
  var MM = tdate.getMonth(); //yields month
  var yyyy = tdate.getFullYear(); //yields year
  var currentDate = dd + "/" + ( MM+1) + "/" + yyyy;
  $('input[name=cb-switch]').is(':checked') {
      $('div#startDate').html(currentDate).appendTo(document);
   }
};
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you call `GetTodayDate()` inside $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Where do you call the `GetTodayDate()` function from? Could wee see the HTML too. Does the `#startDate` div already exist in the DOM? If so you don't need to append it. If it does not then you need to create it before appending it

Comment: Check adding quotes on name value... $('input[name= **"** cb-switch **"** ]')

Comment: @5740382 I did call `GetTodayDate()` inside document.ready but it throws an error

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The startdate div already exists

Comment: that isn't what Rory is asking @NewMike, please read [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408595/jquery-add-todays-date-to-div-when-checkbox-is-checked#comment87832598_50408595) carefully and answer it. **Where do you call the GetTodayDate() function from?**

Comment: What error are you getting? Where does it show up, if not in the console?

Comment: HTML for this is:`<div class="start-date" id="startDate"></div><input type="checkbox" name="cb-switch" value="">`The script is called at the foot of the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a simple example .you can use this code.

I hope is useful for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#myid').change(function() 
        {

            if ($(this).prop('checked')) 
            {
                var tdate = new Date();
                var dd = tdate.getDate(); //yields day
                var MM = tdate.getMonth(); //yields month
                var yyyy = tdate.getFullYear(); //yields year
                var currentDate = dd + "/" + ( MM+1) + "/" + yyyy;
                $('div#startDate').append("<p>"+currentDate+"</p>");
    }
    else {
        alert("You have elected to turn off checkout history."); //not checked
    }
});
    });
</script>
```

`myid` is id of your checkbox

Comment: This worked. Thanks for taking the time to help. And thanks to everyone else for their input.

Answer (score 0):

In your document ready you are missing the click event handler for changes.

```
$('input[name=cb-switch]').click(GetTodayDate)
```

IF you only want to call the function on load do

```
$(document).ready({
    GetTodayDate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a minor issue, `is(':checked')` a Boolean value. and since it is not under if statement it might be saying unexpected {. so change that line of code to:

```
if($('input[name=cb-switch]).is(':checked')) {
      $('div#startDate').html(currentDate);
   }
```

And it will work when you call your method.

To call your method do this:

```
$("input[name=cb-switch]").change(function(){
        GetTodayDate();
    });
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers!!!